# how to update table in another activity in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating and inserting data in a table in an activity named **Customer_page.java** the code is given below:

```
db= openOrCreateDatabase("dsr", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("create table if not exists customer_form" +
                "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                "sales_person TEXT,current_date Text,contact_person TEXT, contact_number TEXT, distance TEXT, description TEXT," +
                "location TEXT, type_of_meeting TEXT,interest TEXT, time_in TEXT, time_out TEXT, flag INTEGER)"
                );
```

and inserting data like this:

```
db.execSQL("insert into customer_form(sales_person,current_date,contact_person,contact_number,distance,description,"+
                        "location,type_of_meeting,interest,time_in,time_out,flag) values" +
                        "('null',date('now'),'"+contact_person+"','"+contact_number+"','"+distance+"','"+description+"','"+location+"','"+type_of_meeting+"','"+interested+"',"+
                                "'"+time_in+"','"+time_out+"',0)");
```

Now i am updating customer_form table in **Welcome.java** activity the code is given below:

```
db=openOrCreateDatabase("dsr", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
db.execSQL("update customer_form set sales_person='"+email_id+"' where sales_person='null'");
    db.close();
```

but this code is not updating table and not giving any error. How can i update customer_form table in **Welcome.java** activity ??

Comment: Why you don't want use update method from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#UpdateDbRow ?

Comment: i want like this...i dont want to use the given method.

Comment: are you sure that in the same activity (Customer_page.java) your code work well ?

Comment: in a same activity it works fine but in another activity not updating.

Comment: I am not sure but check Context, because there are different in getAplicationContex and activity contex

Comment: Thanks for help... I used your given url because i failed to update using my method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the given below code:

First I Made a new class **Database_Update.java**

```
package com.example.hello;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Database_Update extends  SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final String DB_NAME="dsr";
private static final int DB_VER=1;      

public Database_Update(Context context) {
    super(context,DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {     
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int arg1, int arg2) {         
    onCreate(database);
 }
}
```

And then accessed table in my new activity to update:

```
Database_Update du=new Database_Update(this);
    SQLiteDatabase sd=du.getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues value=new ContentValues();
    value.put("sales_person", email_id);
    int updated=sd.update("customer_form", value, "sales_person='no_value'", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"update customer_form set sales_person='"+email_id+"' where sales_person IS NULL  OR sales_person=''"`